# Material date empty condition check Update button disable

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, mat-datepicker

Team,

I am using Angular Mat date picker where I hve a condition that is if any of the mat datepicker is empty my update button should be in disabled mode.

In my code I am checking null but still Button is enabled

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input [disabled]="!enableEdit" [readonly]="inputReadonly" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker"
                        placeholder="Choose a date" [(ngModel)]="item2.firstPatientInDate"
                        (ngModelChange)="dateValidator($event, ii, i)">
                    <!-- (dateChange)="setChange(item2.trialName,'firstPatientInDate', ii, i)" -->
                    <button mat-button *ngIf="item2.firstPatientInDate" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"
                        (click)="clearDate(ii, i, 'firstPatientInDate')">
                        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input [disabled]="!enableEdit" required [readonly]="inputReadonly" matInput [matDatepicker]="n"
                        [ngClass]="{'lpiError': item2.lpiError}" [(ngModel)]="item2.lastPatientInDate"
                        (ngModelChange)="dateValidator($event, ii, i)" [min]="dateFilter(item2.firstPatientInDate)"
                        name="{{i+1}}--{{n}}" placeholder="Choose a date">
                    <!-- (dateChange)="setChange(item2.trialName,'lastPatientInDate', ii, i)" -->
                    <button mat-button *ngIf="item2.lastPatientInDate" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"
                        (click)="clearDate(ii, i, 'lastPatientInDate')">
                        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="n"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #n></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
```

Here is my ts code

```
    disableDate(): boolean {
    let dateError = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption[i].trialDesignElement.length; j++) {
        let date1 = new Date(this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption[i].trialDesignElement[j].firstPatientInDate);
        //console.log(this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption[i].trialDesignElement[j], date1);
        let date2 = new Date(this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption[i].trialDesignElement[j].lastPatientInDate);
        //console.log(this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption[i].trialDesignElement[j], date2);
        if (date1 > date2 && (date1 != null && date2 != null)) {
          // console.log(date1, date2);
          dateError = true;
          this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption[i].trialDesignElement[j]['lpiError'] = true;
          //break;
        } else {
          this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption[i].trialDesignElement[j]['lpiError'] = false;
        }
      }
    }
    return dateError;
}
```

Here is my dateValidator

```
  dateValidator(input: Date | null, ii, i) {
if (input != null) { // null check
  console.log(input, this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption[ii].trialDesignElement[i], Object.prototype.toString.call(input) === '[object Date]', !this.disableDate());
  if ((Object.prototype.toString.call(input) === '[object Date]') && !this.disableDate()) {
    this.disableUpdateBtn = false;
    console.log("Date is Valid!!");
  } else {
    this.disableUpdateBtn = true;
    console.log("Date is Invalid!!");
  }
} else {
  console.log(input, this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption[ii].trialDesignElement[i], Object.prototype.toString.call(input) === '[object Date]', !this.disableDate());
  this.disableUpdateBtn = true;
  console.log("Date is Invalid!!");
}
```

}

dateFilter(firstPatientInDate) {
return new Date(firstPatientInDate);
}

[image]

What I am doing wrong here while I am taking care !=null but still validation is not success here.

Comment: You shoud use ReactiveForms. Using reactive forms you can define the fields as. required and the only this to do is to check if the form is valid. Example can be find within the documentation of angular.io

Comment: @ThomasRenger thanks for your comment but I have all done here Now I can't switch to reactive form

could you please help me here

Comment: @ThomasRenger  thanks for your comment but I have all done here Now I can't switch to reactive form could you please help me here

Answer (score -2):

```js
disableDate(): boolean {
    let dateError = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption[i].trialDesignElement.length; j++) {
        const d1 =         this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption[i].trialDesignElement[j].firstPatientInDate;
        let date1 = new Date(d1);
        //console.log(this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption[i].trialDesignElement[j], date1);
        const d2 = this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption[i].trialDesignElement[j].lastPatientInDate;
        let date2 = new Date(d2);
        //console.log(this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption[i].trialDesignElement[j], date2);
        if (date1 > date2 && (d1 != null && d2 != null)) {
          // console.log(date1, date2);
          dateError = true;
          this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption[i].trialDesignElement[j]['lpiError'] = true;
          //break;
        } else {
          this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption[i].trialDesignElement[j]['lpiError'] = false;
        }
      }
    }
    return dateError;
}
```

I think because you used `let date1 = new Date(...)` and `new Date(null)` is never null.

```js
this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption[i].trialDesignElement[j].firstPatientInDate !== null && 
this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption[i].trialDesignElement[j].lastPatientInDate !== null
```

is current.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Saba Sojoodi means i need put !==null

Comment: so you mean i need to put tlike this 

let date1 =this.milestoneData.maintenanceCountryAssumption[i].trialDesignElement[j].firstPatientInDate !== null

Comment: can you please more clear

Comment: I mean please check it:

Comment: i want to check that way only right in disableDate

Comment: no buddy that way not workiing

Comment: if i removed newDate that won't convert as date format right

Comment: I edit your code and put  it

Comment: @SabaSojoodi just want to understand I did very similarly right

Comment: @SabaSojoodi  i tried your code till that button is enable only

Comment: @SabaSojoodi I have added few more code for reference

Comment: @SabaSojoodi can you please help me here

Comment: did solve your problem?